# Calling Nginx from same system not working, getting 301 Moved permanently

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nginx server with domain name **example.com** and it servers

1. **location /** => for web, running docker at port 8080
2. **location /api** => for API, running docker at port 8090

There is another backend service running in docker at port 9000, which wants to call the API https://example.com/api ... If I try it as localhost:8090 then no issue.

But using https://example.com/api via Nginx returns 301 Moved permanent error.

That is, calling from the same system to Nginx is not working.

Not sure what is wrong.

Please find the nginx conf:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }

    location /api/v1/socketio/ {
        proxy_pass http://lb_autosys_api/socket.io/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gunzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    expires $expires;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your nginx.conf

Comment: added as requested